# Angular, TS searchTerm issue

Tags: javascript, html, angular, search, frontend

Please note that in the example below, when I type something into the search field, it doesn't show me what I just searched. I want it to display only the exact search term that I entered. For instance, if I search for "843190", I would like it to show only "843190".

I tried to change the code like this {

```
search() {
    const searchTerm = this.field.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    const rows = this.field.rowsToFilter.filter(row => {
      return this.field.columns.some(column => {
        const cell = row[column.name];
        if (column.checkbox) {
          return cell.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);
        }
        if (column.datepicker) {
          return cell.data.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);
        }
        if (column.select) {
          return cell.option.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);
        }
        return cell.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);
      });
    });
  
    this.field.rows = rows;
    this.field.total = rows.length;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.field.rowsToFilter.filter( row => this.matches(row, this.field.searchTerm));
  }
```

Comment: Could you please post a code where you define the class property `field`?

Comment: did you meant this ?  @Input() public parentField: FieldConfig;
  @Input() public fields: FieldConfig[];
  @Input() public field: FieldConfig;
  @Input() public group: FormGroup;
  @Input() public page: string;
  @Input() public fieldsDates: string[] = [];

Comment: I meant to initial property `field` declaration and assignment from parent component in your case. There's unclear what's the purpose of `searchTerm`, etc... Or even better to create reproducible example on Stackblitz.